# Dealing with different error types in `ExceptT` computation

Tags: haskell, error-handling, either

(This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27051454/459877) but that question only received a comment recommending the `errors` package, I would like some more details.)

I'm working on a program that uses two different packages that both return types `IO (Either e a)` or `Either e a`. However the `e` is not the same between the libraries.

I wonder how to structure functions that use both libraries. The hint that I should use `errors` led me to `hush` and `note`, but this doesn't feel quite right:

```
data MyError = Error1 | Error2 | Error3

f :: IO (Either MyErrorType Text)
f = do
  now <- someIoAction

  runExceptT $ do
    x <- note Error1 $ hush LibraryA.f
    y <- ExceptT $ note Error2 . hush <$> LibraryB.IO.f
    z <- ExceptT $ note Error3 . hush <$> LibraryB.IO.g
    pure (x, y, z)
```

How should one structure code like this? Should I match on results and convert the error types? Are there something else in the `errors` package that I should know about? I will be really grateful for an answer to the (somewhat) specific question about how to structure code like the one above and general pointers to dealing with non-uniform errors in Haskell.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to work in `Either (Either e1 e2) a` or `ExceptT (Either e1 e2) m a`, using eg `withExceptT` to embed each smaller computation into the bigger one. This approach starts to get clunky when you have lots of error types to deal with (though it seems you only have two for now).

Comment: It really depends on the context. If you want to write some code which works now without investing inordinate amounts of time into how 'good' you can make it (this rabbit-hole is very deep), then your solution is fine. If you are using the library functions thousands of times in this way, then just define a few simple wrappers which have an appropriately general type and use those wrappers instead of the library functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the error only once, I'd transform `IO (Either e a)` into `IO a` with a utility function like this:

```
throwWhenLeft :: Exception e => IO (Either e a) -> IO a
throwWhenLeft io = either throwIO return =<< io
```

This looks dangerous at a glance, but it's useful in some (very common, IMO) cases:

- You have to handle various Exception thrown/returned either by `IO a` or some `Either e a`.
- What exception handlers' do is almost always same.